# Play audio onclick with multiple entries

Tags: android, onclick

Code below can play an audio file after Onclick of an ImageView.
What should I do if have multiple entries (let's say 3-5)?
With just short amount of codes for the 3-5 entries?

The Code below will play "Good Morning" audio.
What should i do to play "Good Evening", "Good Afternoon" etc. with as simple code as this without repeating this code.

Java:

```
ImageView one = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.good_morning_mp3);
    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.good_morning);
    one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v) {
            mp.start();
        }
    });
```

XML:

```
ImageView
android:id="@+id/good_morning_mp3"
android:padding="5dp"
android:layout_width="48dp"
android:layout_height="48dp"
android:src="@drawable/ic_play_circle_outline_black_48dp"
android:tint="@color/v2colorPrimary"
/>
```

UPDATE: What to fix here? It is not playing any audio.

```
public void onClick(View view) {
        if(view.getId() == R.id.good_morning_mp3){
            final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.good_morning);
            mp.start();
        }else if(view.getId() == R.id.good_afternoon_mp3){
            final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.good_afternoon);
            mp.start();
        }else if(view.getId() == R.id.good_evening_mp3){
            final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.good_evening);
            mp.start();
        }
    }
```

**New Update: I was looking for a version like this for playing an audio.**

This code is getting the TAG Value of an ImageView and I use the value of it to be used on a function.

e.g. The tag value of the ImageView is a number. When I tapped the Imageview, It will dial the number.

JAVA:

```
public void CallPhone(View call) {
        // Get instance of Vibrator from current Context
        Vibrator v2 = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        // Vibrate for 400 milliseconds
        v2.vibrate(100);
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+call.getTag()));
        startActivity(callIntent);
}
```

XML:

```
 <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="end"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:background="@color/v2colorPrimary"
                        android:onClick="TextPhone"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_textsms_black_18dp"
                        android:tag="09079338303"
                        android:tint="#fff" />
```

Comment: are you trying to show the imageview in a list?

Comment: @3iL No. Just a simple screen with with at least 3-5 buttons that if tapped, will play an audio.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. You have to call saperate onclicks on your imageviews and then try calling different audio files

Comment: It's okay. Can you please update your answer based on your suggestion?

Comment: please have a look

Comment: Hi 3iL, Yes. It works! This is somewhat I'm looking for. But I was thinking of a more compressed version of this? like a shorter line of codes because what we did here is like we only duplicate the onclicks. Let me show you a code that I have.

Comment: Please check. Thank you!

Comment: If you want separate buttons that do different things there is no other way to do it except the one I posted. A more efficient way to do it will be to create a listview of imageviews and then create a POJO class for your audio files and phone numbers and then in your list's base adapter you can call your imageviews by position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand you can do something like this:

```
ImageView one = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.good_morning_mp3_1);
ImageView two = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.good_morning_mp3_2);
ImageView three = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.good_morning_mp3_3);
    final MediaPlayer mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.good_morning_1);
final MediaPlayer mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.good_morning_2);
final MediaPlayer mp3 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.good_morning_3);
    one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v) {
            mp1.start();
        }
    });
    two.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v) {
            mp2.start();
        }
    });
three.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v) {
            mp3.start();
        }
    });
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: Please tell me what is wrong here:

public void onClick(View view) {
        if(view.getId() == R.id.good_morning_mp3){
            final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.good_morning);
            mp.start();
        }else if(view.getId() == R.id.good_afternoon_mp3){
            final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.good_afternoon);
            mp.start();
        }else if(view.getId() == R.id.good_evening_mp3){
            final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.good_evening);
            mp.start();
        }
    }

Comment: Post this in your question  so it's better to understand

Comment: Done. Please check.

Comment: you have the exact same thing in every condition. In your xml make three different imageviews with different IDs and then try playing different audio files for every imageview